# Regex for getting domain name from Referer

Tags: regex

Am using the following regex to capture different parts of referer url. I want to capture protocol and domain and used it in diff scenarios.

```
Pattern pr=new Patters("^\w+://|[^\/:]+|[\w\W]*$");
```

But eclipse is giving me and error

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )..
```

Am new to regex. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I had a problem so I decided to use regexps - now I've got two problems...

Comment: `[\w\W]*` will match anything, even an empty string.

Comment: @M42 doesn't actually matter in this case, as he's not using that field.

Comment: @Alnitak: right, but his pattern will match any string.

Comment: @M42 yes, given the incorrect `|` characters in it

Comment: You can do this with regexes, but you will be better off using the java's [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URI.html) class. There, you can do: `(new URI(referrer)).getHost()` and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

You're supply a string to the `Pattern` constructor, so you need to escape the backslashes.

e.g.:

```
Pattern pr = new Pattern("^\\w+://|[^/:]+|[\\w\\W]*$");
```

Your regexp is *probably* not complete - you need to "group" the scheme and domain sections with brackets:

```
Pattern pr = new Pattern("^(\\w+)://([^/:]+)");
```

I've ignored everything after the next colon or slash - you said you only wanted the scheme and domain.

Answer (score 0):

Regex uses "\"(i.g., \w, \W, \d, \D) as the starting character to define regex syntax. Java also uses "\" as well. Java also allows "\" to be used by adding an extra "\", so you would end up with "\\" in your code, this will escape the other backslash.

Just in case your solution in not what you expected try using "regexpal.com".
Remember, whenever you expect a single slash("\") in your outcome use a double slash("\\") in your code.